# How can change event's 'this' object to other function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I have multiple rows containing file upload control, on onchange event of particular rows fileupload control I'm picking first columns text and sending its value through ajax request.

```
$(document).on('change','#uploadSupportingDoc',function(){
   console.log("on change called!");
   var questionId = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text(); // 1st column

   console.log("fileUpload called with Id =>"+questionId);
   uploadFile(questionId,this);

});
```

However there is one column( with css class .fileuploadSuccess ) where I want to change icon to show success or failure of uploading.

```
function uploadFile(questionId,row){
console.log("fileUpload called with Id =>"+questionId);

var isUploaded = false;
$('#uploadSupportingDoc').fileupload({
    url: 'uploadSupportingDoc.html',
    formData: {questionId: questionId },
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(jpe?g)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 100,
    dropZone: null,
    pasteZone: null,
    fileInput: $(this),
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function(e, data){

        $(row).closest('tr').children('td.fileuploadSuccess').html('<img src="./img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Uploading..." />');
        data.submit();
    },
    done: function (e, data){
        var response = data.result.files[0];

        if(!response.isRequestValid)
        {
            window.location = "requestDenied.html";
        }
        else
        {
            if(response.status)
            {
                $(row).closest('tr').children('td.fileuploadSuccess').html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>")
            }
            else
            {
                $(row).closest('tr').children('td.fileuploadSuccess').html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>")               
            }
        }
    },
    fail: function(e, data){
        console.log("failed");
        console.log(data.jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(data.jqXHR+"\m");
    },
    always: function (e, data){

    }
 });


}
```

I've tried sending it this way,

```
uploadFile(questionId,this);
```

and tried to access it like this,

```
$(row).closest('tr').children('td.fileuploadSuccess').html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>");
```

Howerer this is not working and everytime it is changing the value of first rows column. why is it happening? any solution for this kind of requirement?

Comment: Do you have a copy online we can play with?

Comment: unfortunate I don't have codebase right now, will post jsfiddle by tomorrow.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using same id for every row "#uploadSupportingDoc"? It might be the issue as id selector always returns first object.

Comment: not really, but I'm creating these row dynamically. this is actually add/update/delete kinda table.

Comment: Did you try with 'class' or you can't change id's and need some another way around?

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to pass row there.
Pass the element for which you want to update html:

```
$(document).on('change','#uploadSupportingDoc',function(){
   console.log("on change called!");
   var questionId = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text(); // 1st column
   console.log("fileUpload called with Id =>"+questionId);

   var cell = $(this).parent().siblings('.fileuploadSuccess');
   uploadFile(questionId, cell);

});
```

Change `function uploadFile(questionId,row){` to `function uploadFile(questionId,cell){`

You can then simplify:
 `$(row).closest('tr').children('td.fileuploadSuccess').html(..);`

to 
`cell.html(...);`

Comment: $(row).closest('tr').children('td.fileuploadSuccess').html("icon_here"); row is actually the parameter name consisting 'this' variable.  with your provided solution how can access child td having css class fileuploadSuccess?